# Can AWS Glue handle foreign key exceptions?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am trying to load data into a table that has foreign key relationships. I need to find out of there is a way to handle this foreign key violation error through aws glue. Expectation is, if there is any violation, it should move to next record and ignore the one failing.

After apply transformation, this is the default code for reference.

```
# Script generated for node Data Catalog table
DataCatalogtable_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    database="test-db",
    table_name="test-table",
    transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node3",
)
 
job.commit()
```

I just need to know if it is possible to handle this scenario.

We have used lambda to use try-except scenario. but lambda has 15 min limit. We are exploring aws glue for loading data. We are able to load data into the table that does not have any foreign key relationships. Not sure how to move ahead with handling exceptions.